# send a multicast audio in rtsp using libstreaming for upstreaming from an android device

Tags: android, audio-streaming, rtsp

The code is only streaming for one user at a time. Can anyone help me to play the stream in more than one system at the same time(convert it to multicast or broadcast).
Thanks in advance.

The library source is over here:
https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

my current code is:

```
    mSurfaceView = (net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

    // Sets the port of the RTSP server to 1234
    Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putString(RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(5060));                                                            // audio port num               
    editor.commit();

    // Configures the SessionBuilde
    SessionBuilder.getInstance()
    .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
    .setPreviewOrientation(90)
    .setContext(getApplicationContext())
    .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
    .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_NONE);


    MainActivity.this.startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,RtspServer.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the code at github and seems that you only need to specify the multicast address to the `SessionBuilder` class and then the underlying RTSP server and RTP transport should handle everything (at least the RTSP responses seem have code to produce correct transport descriptions). So I guess adding a `setDestination` call to your `SessionBuilder` configuration should be ok (replace the 232.0.1.2 with the address you need):

```
// Configures the SessionBuilde
SessionBuilder.getInstance()
.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
.setPreviewOrientation(90)
.setContext(getApplicationContext())
.setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
.setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_NONE)
.setDestination("232.0.1.2");
```

The clients will still connect to the RTSP server through it's address but the actual RTP stream should be single and shared among all the clients.

Comment: Hello. I don't understand what the destination address correspond to. It seems it's not the address of the Android Server nor the list of the client IPs. So can you explain what it is, how to define it, and if there must be a piece of software listening at this address? Thanks!

Comment: Well it's an ordinary multicast address that is used by the server. Since multicast is UDP then you don't need to listen, bust just call connectionless receive functions like `recfrom` in C while the server just does `sendto`.